# Testing p(a|b) using 2 dice

Tags: probability

```
p(a|b) = p(a,b) / p(b)
```

Working this out

Given two fairly sided dice each thrown once what is the probability of 1 or 2 in either dice ?

```
a = 1
b = 2
```

Using above formula :

p(a given b) = 1/6 (as both throws of dice are mutually exclusive, the probability of `b` does not impact probability of `a`)

so this gives :

```
p(a|b) = 1/6(probability of a given b) / 1/6(probability b) = 1
```

As probability is between 0 & 1 then this is incorrect.

Where is the mistake in my logic ? I think my understanding of probability of event given a separate event is incorrect ?

Comment: do you have two dices ? with independent trials ?

Comment: You need to clarify your question with how many dice are being thrown, if it is a fair six-sided die, and what is given.

Comment: and one dice with two independent trial ?

Comment: Assuming you mean one trial with one die, then isn't $p(a\cap b)=0$?

Comment: @Cardinal question updated

Comment: @blue-sky each one them are throwing two times ?

Comment: @Cardinal each dice is thrown once, question updated

Comment: Ok, do these throws are independent ?

Comment: @Cardinal yes, each throw is independent & mutually exclusive

Comment: so what about $P_r(a|b)=P_r(a)$ ?

Comment: @blue-sky see the answer, i wish it help you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look below:

$$P_r(a|b)=P_r(a)=\frac{1/36}{1/6}=1/6$$
notice that, since $a$ and $b$ are independent, we have
$$ P_r(a\cap b)=P_r(a,b)=P_r(a)P_r(b)$$

Comment: is p(a,b) = p(a intersection b) ?

Comment: yes, i am editing it :)

Comment: or another way p(a,b) = p(a and b)

Comment: @blue-sky I strongly suggest you read the books about random variables.