# Is this a contradiction in probability?

Tags: probability

In this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1365989/testing-pab-using-2-dice)
:

$$ P_r(a\cap b)=P_r(a,b)=P_r(a)P_r(b)$$

However in this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/156852/what-do-did-you-do-to-remember-bayes-rule/156866#156866):

$$p(a,b) = p(a|b)p(b) = p(b|a)p(a)$$

Is this a contradiction as $P_r(a)P_r(b) \ne p(b|a)p(a)$ ?

Comment: Keyword: independence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No because the two dice are independent the outcome on one has no effect on the other so: $p(a,b)=p(a)p(b)=p(b|a)p(a)$ hence $p(b|a)=p(b)$ (note the first equality is the definition of independence in this context: RVs $A$ and $B$ are independent iff $\mbox{prob}(A=a,B=b)=\mbox{prob}(A=a)\times \mbox{prob}(B=b)$ )

Comment: so p(a,b) = p(a) p(b) if the events are independent and p(a , b) = p(a) intersection p(b) if the events are not independent ?

Answer (score 0):

The second example is the general case of Bayes' rule.  In the first example, the two events are independent so $p(b|a) = p(b)$.

Answer (score 0):

$P(A \cup B) = P(A)P(B)$ only holds if $A$ and $B$ are independent. 
In that case they have no effect on each other. Then it shouldn't be a suprise that $$P(B | A) = \frac{P(A\cup B)}{P(A)} = \frac{P(A)P(B)}{P(A)}=P(B)$$